# Update Customer Profile

Tags: php, html

As a customer, I have no problem in displaying my details/profile but I can't update/edit my profile even though I have clicked the "Save" button. Am I missing something here?

edit_customer_profile.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include 'connection.php'; 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['CustomerID'])) {
    $customerID = $_SESSION['CustomerID'];
    $customername = $_SESSION['CustomerName'];  

    $customers = mysql_query("select * from customer where CustomerID='".$customerID."'");
    $customer = mysql_num_rows($customers);

    if($customer== 1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($customers);
        $email = $row['CustomerEmail'];
        $contactno = $row['CustomerContactNo'];
        $class = $row['CustomerClass'];
        $campus = $row['CustomerCampus'];
        $intake = $row['CustomerIntake'];


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
        $_var1 = $_POST['new_name'];
        $_var2 = $_POST['new_email'];
        $_var3 = $_POST['new_contactno'];
        $_var4 = $_POST['new_campus'];
        $_var5 = $_POST['new_intake'];
        $_var6 = $_POST['new_class'];

        $query1 = "UPDATE customer 
                        SET CustomerName='$_var1', CustomerEmail='$_var2', CustomerContactNo='$_var3', CustomerCampus='$_var4', CustomerIntake='$_var5', CustomerClass='$_var6' 
                        WHERE CustomerID='$customerID'";
    }   
    }
}
 ?>
```

Below is the form

```
<form method = "post" action=">
            <tr>
                <td width="170">Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" value="<?php echo $customername ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="new_email" size="30" value="<?php echo $email ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact No:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="new_contactno" size="30" value="<?php echo $contactno ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Campus:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="new_campus" size="30" value="<?php echo $campus ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Intake:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="new_intake" size="30" value="<?php echo $intake ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>                    
                <td>Class:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="new_class" size="30" value="<?php echo $class ?>" /></td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><input type="submit" size="30" name="submit" value="Save" /></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't run the update query.

Run your update query with

```
$query1 = "UPDATE customer 
           SET 
           CustomerName='$_var1', 
           CustomerEmail='$_var2', 
           CustomerContactNo='$_var3', 
           CustomerCampus='$_var4', 
           CustomerIntake='$_var5', CustomerClass='$_var6' 
           WHERE CustomerID='$customerID'";

mysql_query($query1);
```

Note: Use mysqli_* or pdo_* functions instead of mysql_ functions, which is going to deprecated.

Comment: Where do i put that line?

Comment: It works and i can update all but name. The name is updated on phpmyadmin but does not update on my website. why?

Comment: seems you are displaying the customer name in the website from session variable. you need to update the session variable once update has been done. you need to select 'CustomerName' in your select query